# Probability of needing at least 10 draws to get a specific card (king).

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What's the probability of having to draw at least 10 cards in order to get a king from a regular deck of 52 cards?

As far as I understand, the probability is:

$1-(P(X=1)+P(X=2)+...+P(X=9))$

Where P(X=1):

$4/52$

And P(X=2):
$\frac{48}{52}\frac{4}{51}+\frac{4}{52}\frac{48}{51}+\frac{4}{52}\frac{3}{51}$

And so on.

Is my logic correct, and which distribution can I use to calculate the final result more easily (I believe cumulative negative hypergeometric)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my logic correct, and which distribution can I use to calculate the final result more easily (I believe cumulative negative hypergeometric)?

Your logic is correct, but it will only get more complicated.   However, yes, the *count of kings among a sample of given size is hypergeometrically distributed*, leading to a much easier way to evaluate.

Put it this way : The probability of having to draw *at least* 10 cards before encountering a king is the probability that *no king* is encountered among the *first nine* cards drawn from the deck.

> $$1-\dfrac{\dbinom{4}{0}~\dbinom{48}{9}}{\dbinom{52}9}$$